Should statistics-heavy questions be directed to Cross Validated?
I have noticed a lot of questions on QF that are 90% or more about statistics and hardly depend on the financial application at hand. Since there exists a sister site Cross Validated for statistical questions, wouldn't it be sensible to direct such questions there?

They fit there well
They could attract faster and probably higher-quality responses

I know it is important to get enough traction while QF is still Beta, and getting rid of question goes in the opposite direction, but aside of that, doesn't the idea make sense?

From my point of view, you shouldn't. Take a look at CV's time-series tag. If you ask a question related to that take, you're most likely never to get an answer. However, in QF you'll probably get an answer...

@Anoldmaninthesea., I don't quite understand. There are a lot of time series questions on Cross Validated (that is the fourth most popular tag there), and a large proportion get answered. A lot of the statistical questions that get asked here would be answered faster on CV, I think (and I have been an active participants at CV for the last 2 years). Also, asking statistical questions on different sites would create some mess in that users would have to visit different sites to look for answers; I think this goes against the basic logic.

From my experience, it's the fourth most popular tag there, but the proportion of answered questions is much lower than similar popular tags. 43% are left unanswered. Compare with machine learning tag: only 39.5% are unanswered...

@Anoldmaninthesea, Probably it has to do with the quality of the questions that varies across tags, I am not sure. I don't think there is a lack of answerers for time series on CV. Also, statistical questions here are not only on time series. But even if there was a problem with some types of questions on CV, it would still make little sense to spread the clearly statistical questions over different sites. Probably it would be better to try attracting the missing people there. E.g. guys that are answering purely statistical questions here could explore CV and find some material to work on.

Honestly I doubt you would be able to attract people... Maybe. It's definitely worth a shot at least.  It would make my life easier when asking questions.
